# download repository from github directly to your laravel website

Tags: javascript, git, laravel, github

I am making  a Resources page on my website where i am going to put all my plugins and packages and other stuff ..
i was wondering if there is a way to straightly download a github repository to your client's computer when he clicks a link. or using some javascript or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each repository has a download link (clone/download). Copy the download links from each repository and create anchor tags.

Thats the easy way and will get you going quickly.

Alternatively, if looking for an automated way, the API is robust:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Comment: i'll preffer the api. Thank you i'll take a look at the api section